# Android :Declared Global variables becoming null while running the app?

Tags: android

I'm using this class.

I'm new to android, I have declared global variables in one class. and I'm using that variables across the multiple activities,but these global variables are becoming null while running may app only in low memory devices and version I'm using for testing 2.3.6

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: you mean your variables become null from some other value?Do you do initialization for them ?

Comment: can you post that class, where you declared that global variable?

Comment: this is the class i'm using

Comment: @sravani Why did you self-vandalize your question by removing the code?

Answer (score 1):

Try Like This:

Create a shared data class:

**SharedData.java**

```
public class SharedData {

    private static SharedData instance = new SharedData();

    // Getter-Setters
    public static SharedData getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public static void setInstance(SharedData instance) {
        SharedData.instance = instance;
    }

    private int notification_index;


    private SharedData() {

    }


    public int getNotification_index() {
        return notification_index;
    }


    public void setNotification_index(int notification_index) {
        this.notification_index = notification_index;
    }



}
```

Declared/Initiaze an instance of class globally in classes where you want to set/get data:

```
SharedData sharedData = SharedData.getInstance();
```

Set data:

```
sharedData.setNotification_index(123);
```

Get data:

```
int n = sharedData.getNotification_index();
```

Comment: Doesn't work, static variable also can be set to null by system.

Answer (score 0):

There are few solutions to it:

- Extend the Application class for storing global values, and that
  class will be   available across you activities.
- Save in SharedPreferences(**This is the easiest and reliable way to save and retrieve global data**).
- Save in database(Sqlite db).
- Also, you can save in SDcard or internal memory.

  **Let us know How you are trying to store value and at which point it's value is getting reset.**

Example code for First option:

```
public class GlobalValue extends Application {

     private int value = 0;

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

     public void setValue(int value) {
         this.value = gameScore;
     }
     public void incrementValue(){
         value++;
     }

 }
```

Declare this class in Manifest file :

```
 1: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    2:    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    3:     package="com.example"
    4:     android:versionCode="1"
    5:     android:versionName="1.0" >
    6:
    7:      <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />
    8:
    9:      <application
    10:         android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    11:         android:label="@string/app_name"
    12:         android:name="GlobalState" >
    13:
    14:         <!-- component definitions -->
    15:     </application>
    16:
    17:   </manifest>
```

Comment: how to implent second one

Comment: if we declared like in first one is it run in low memory devices?

Comment: Please check this [Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFileBasedPersistence/article.html) for sharedpreference. If you want you can even save Objects in SharedPreference.First one will also run without any problem, but check before saving you may need static variable to save those data

Answer (score 0):

I think you are creating instance of that class each time in your all activities. 
declare all variable as "public static final" in that class

if you want to use that global variable than you just code like this in your activities.

```
 SQRUtils.downloader = // change which you want//

SQRUtils.mGson = //if you want to change mgson value//
```

and you can get all data each time in all class .after stop that application this variable will be delete.

Comment: thanq for your answer

Comment: i'm using like this only