# Android - Why do Global Variables defined in Application become null?

Tags: android, memory

Using Crashlytics I have become aware of some crashes occurring in my application that seem to be related to global variables becoming null while the application is running.

I have read the following two stackflows, but I am not sure they fully apply to my circumstances (though maybe someone can point out how they do):

[Android :Declared Global variables becoming null while running the app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21373726/android-declared-global-variables-becoming-null-while-running-the-app)

[Global variable becomes null sometimes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22487248/global-variable-becomes-null-sometimes)

First, the application is designed not to "run" in the background. I know that when the home button is hit that it will continue to run in the background, but it cannot be pulled from the background back into operation, rather you are forced to restart the app. So I don't think this is a problem of the app global memory being deallocated, unless in the restart it is trying to use the old version running in the background (and on some devices it seems to just go away).

Second, I am unable to replicate the error of the memory being deallocated on any of my devices. It almost seems to happen in various random places in the application, though pretty rarely. I have tried letting it go to sleep, rerunning, waking it up, re-installing, everything I can think of without success.

Third, if this does happen, is there a way to get that global memory back to where it was and some event that would trigger my saving it and and event to re-establish it?

The previous blogs have talked about low power devices, or devices with low memory potentially causing this. But in looking at it, the devices seem to have lots of battery still. Could they potentially have a lot of other apps running in the background chewing up memory causing a collection of my apps memory?

Here is a sample of the global memory class being employed...

```
public class GlobalState extends Application {

    public Form currentForm = null;
    public int currentUserId = -1;
    public int currentAccountId = -1;
    public int currentSubformIndex = 0;
    public Context context = null;
    public AndroidLogger logger = null;

    private static GlobalState instance;

    public static GlobalState getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        instance = this; 
        instance.context = getApplicationContext();
        logger = AndroidLogger.getLogger(getApplicationContext(), "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    }

}
```

Forgive me if this is something really obvious, still fairly new to Android

Answer (score -1):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8023552 might have some info you're interested. Perhaps your application is having onPause() then later onReusme() called, and you're not properly saving state to a Bundle? If you try overriding the onSaveInstanceState method, you might be able to ensure those variables stick around.

Comment: Thanks! I was doing some research on the onSaveInstanceState, mostly in regards to recovering my Activity state data. But my worry is that since this is global data for the Application, and the form can sometimes hold upwards of 10mb worth of data (which might be why it is getting deallocated!) saving the data could get messy. Have a fair number of activities and would hate to have to save and restore this global data when any `onPause` or `onResume` occurred. What I am really curious about is how this is happening and perhaps intercepting or recovering from it when I see it coming.

Comment: Application class will be executed on every component invocation like activity service and receivers. So you may have to guard your global data from second execution onwards.

Comment: @7383 Good to know that. Would that include when the device goes to sleep? What operations comprise the "activity service and receivers"? I suspect the global data for the "currentForm" is the main culprit...I will have to look to see if a onCreate call a second tile would reset the data.